# Java Task stop after loop

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, task

in my project I have this code.

```
    Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call()  throws Exception {
        do {
            ...
            [do something]
            ...
        } while (true);
        [do other]
        return null;
    }
};
new Thread(task).start();
```

The loop working fine, but the istruction out of loop [do other] are not executed.
Can you help me to understand?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The "while(true)" is only an example.
The loop working until the condition is true!
The real command is "while(x < y)" and working fine!

This code WORK

```
                Callable<Void> task = new Callable<Void>() {
              @Override
              public  Void call()  throws Exception {

                    do {
                        rowBin = new ASN1BinaryModel("000A" , "A0", "80", "54", "31", "0F", "0B", "A0", "80", "54", "31", "0F", "0B", "A0", "80", "54", "31");
                        asn1BinaryTable.getItems().add(rowBin);

                        countTotByte = countTotByte + 16;

                        System.out.println("HEX: " + countTotByte);

                    } while (countTotByte <= len);
                    System.out.println("END LOOP");
                  return null;
```

This code NOT WORK

```
                Callable<Void> task = new Callable<Void>() {
              @Override
              public  Void call()  throws Exception {

                    do {
                        tmpAddress = Integer.toHexString(countTotByte).toUpperCase();
                        rowBin = new ASN1BinaryModel(String.format("%4s", tmpAddress).replace(" ", "0") , String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte]), 
                                String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+1]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+2]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+3]), 
                                String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+4]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+5]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+6]),
                                String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+7]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+8]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+9]), 
                                String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+10]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+11]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+12]), 
                                String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+13]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+14]), String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+15]));

                        asn1BinaryTable.getItems().add(rowBin);

                        countTotByte = countTotByte + 16;

                        System.out.println("HEX: " + countTotByte);

                    } while (countTotByte <= len);
                    System.out.println("END LOOP");
                  return null;
```

Comment: Likely one of the written-to variables is shared, declared outside the thread under the hood makes a copy of exteral variables, and synchronizes on specific points when the variable is volatile. Make such a variable `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

`do { ... } while (true)` keeps looping.

Try using a variable instead of `true` and set this variable to `false`. The loop will end and `[do other]` will get executed.

I'm not sure about your `Task`, but changed to `Callable` and `ExecutorService`:

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Callable<Void> task = new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                i++;
                System.out.println(i);
            } while (i < 10);
            System.out.println("end");
            return null;
        }
    };

     ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
     executor.submit(task);

}
```

Output:

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10
> end
> ```

Comment: I am sorry, "while (true)" is an example.
The loop run untiil a variable is minor of another variable:

while (x < y)

I modify the example

Comment: Just make sure that happens :) Because if `x>=y` the loop will exit.

Comment: I'm sure. 
I have test the loop with a printout and working fine.

Comment: Without more code (see: sscce.org)  it's hard to say why then.

Comment: RobAu, i try your solution and work... but, i think the problem is the my instruction in [do sometingh] 
I add update to my question

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have an infinite loop. make sur that x >= y in some how after some executions of the loop in order to get out of it.

Comment: The loop working fine.
In the [do something] i set the exit value from loop

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am idiot... sorry
The problem is in byte data[] array.

I read a file and insert bytes in data[size] where [size] is file lenght.
After i get 16 byte to time and adding row to TableView.
The problem si the last X bytes, because is not sure that they are 16!
In this way the command:

```
String.format("%02X", data[countTotByte+n])
```

fails when finds the first byte[] "empty".

I am sorry again...